Using github app to install private repos across organizations?
Apologizes if this is a duplicate. I have found different variations of this all over the internet but am still having issues. See the below scenario.
I have two github organizations.
Org1 - has private Repo1
Org2 - has a repo that has a dependency on private Repo1 from Org1 which will be installed via pip
My question is, what is the prescribed pattern to follow in order to achieve this? On previous projects we would create a service account under Org2 and generate a SSH key to assign to the user, add them as a readonly collaborator for Repo1 and then associate any machines or github actions with the private key for the service account to pip install or clone the repo.
I am reading about github apps and I am curious if there a way to achieve this using github apps that is a more desirable/secure pattern? Any code for doing this is greatly appreciated.

I was curious as well and asked ChatGPT about a possible solution using python and github actions. The answer would be worth testing in your case, seems to work!
